# How can my client post new articles without touching to the code?

Tags: html, client, addition, edit

I have to code a little html site in my informatic class and we have to give it to a client when finished. The thing is, he wants to be able to add posts regulary without having to go into the code. Is there a way to, like, translate raw text into an all-ready

tag and automatically implement it on the website ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use wordpress. Is it possible to convert your website to wordpress template? It have admin panel, also there is application for iOS. You could post through emails. It is quite complicated to make it by yourself as there are few security issues you have to be aware. Other way is to use other frameworks like http://get-simple.info which uses text databases in files.

Comment: get-simple is surpricely easy and quick to use. You can convert your template/page in minutes.